# AttributeError: 'TextDataset' object has no attribute 'cardinality' when training with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I am trying to finetune a large language model with text data from a .txt file.

I load up the dataset with the class TextDatase from transformers:

```
train_dataset = TextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path=file_path,
    block_size=128
)
```

Then I declare the training arguments:

```
training_args = TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./finetuned_model",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    save_steps=10_000,
    save_total_limit=2,
)
```

Last, I declare the TFTrainer and finetune the model:

```
trainer = TFTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
)


# This line while hopefully finetune the model based on my data
trainer.train()
```

However, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'TextDataset' object has no attribute 'cardinality'`

And this error is detailed in the following log:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[14], line 44
> 36 trainer = TFTrainer(
> 37     model=model,
> 38     args=training_args,
> 39     train_dataset=train_dataset,
> 40 )
> 43 # Fine-tune the model
> 44 trainer.train()
> 46 # Save the fine-tuned model
> 47 model.save_pretrained("./finetuned_model")
>
> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer_tf.py:479, in TFTrainer.train(self)
> 475 def train(self) -> None:
> 476     """
> 477     Train method to train the model.
> 478     """
> 479     train_ds = self.get_train_tfdataset()
> 481     if self.args.debug:
> 482         tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
>
> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer_tf.py:159, in TFTrainer.get_train_tfdataset(self)
> 156     raise ValueError("Trainer: training requires a train_dataset.")
> 158 self.total_train_batch_size = self.args.train_batch_size * self.args.gradient_accumulation_steps
> 159 self.num_train_examples = self.train_dataset.cardinality().numpy()
> 161 if self.num_train_examples < 0:
> 162     raise ValueError("The training dataset must have an asserted cardinality")
>
> AttributeError: 'TextDataset' object has no attribute 'cardinality'

All my packages are up to date. I have no idea what to do next.
Please help.

I have tried creating a custom tenserflow data set but it didnt work.

The attempt was comprised of trying this solution:

```
def generator():
    for example in train_dataset.examples:
        yield tokenizer(example["text"], truncation=True, padding="max_length", max_length=128)

num_elements = len(train_dataset.examples)

train_tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(128,), dtype=tf.int32), args=[])

train_tf_dataset = train_tf_dataset.take(num_elements)
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `TFTrainer` is not [maintained](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/26632) by [Huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/27110#issuecomment-1783057578) anymore. You should use [Keras API](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/26632#issuecomment-1750960315) to train your model.